# Angular bootstrap tab ng-if bug

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

When using ng-if on a tab if that statement returns true then the second tab will be active instead of the first.

```
<tabset>
    <tab heading="Static title" ng-if="aaa == true">Static content</tab>
    <tab heading="tab2">Content 2</tab>
</tabset>
```

i feel like ive tried everything but with no luck.

here is an example of the problem:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Hpif920RrB6nS4AB4Mwj?p=preview

I hope some of you might be able to help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try use active attribute. like this

```
<tabset>
  <tab heading="Static title" active="aaa == true" >Static content</tab>
  <tab heading="tab2">Content 2</tab>
</tabset>
```

Comment: i want the tab to be totally gone if aaa is false so sadly this does not work :(

Comment: u can do - <tab heading="Static title" active="aaa == true" ng-if="aaa=== true">Static content</tab>

Answer (score 1):

Not really a bug, it looks like `<tabset>` is changing the scope, therefore `aaa` would refer to whichever controller `<tabset>` has created. Refer to your own controller, `TabsDemoCtrl.aaa`

```
<tabset>
    <tab heading="Static title" ng-if="TabsDemoCtrl.aaa == true">Static content</tab>
    <tab heading="tab2">Content 2</tab>
</tabset>
```

EDIT: If you inspect your DOM elements, you can actually see `<tabset>` is using an isolated scope: `tabbable ng-isolate-scope`

Answer (score 0):

```
<tabset>
  <tab heading="Static title" active="aaa == true" ng-if="aaa=== true">Static content</tab>
  <tab heading="tab2">Content 2</tab>
</tabset>
```

That should work

Answer (score 0):

This is because value inside `aaa` is true hence it display static title but you have not added code for activation so it is not activated. change code by

```
<tab heading="Static title" ng-if="aaa" active="aaa">Static content</tab>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody like me still having this issue after 5 years this question was asked.

ng-if is the directive to determine you have this tab or remove this tab. No matter what, the first tab should be activated as default if no 'active' is specified on any tab, but here when you have a ng-if the default behaviour will be changed. Nothing wrong with the scope, the expression etc.

Add ng-if on all the tabs, for those you don't need it, just add ng-if="true", this will make the default activated tab to normal.

```
<tabset>
   <tab heading="Static title" ng-if="aaa == true">Static content</tab>
   <tab heading="tab2" ng-if="true">>Content 2</tab>
</tabset>
```